# Scala permutations using two lists

Tags: scala

What would be the best way to achieve the following please?
I have two lists:

```
val l1 = List("a", "b") 
val l2 = List(1, 2)
```

and I would like to generate this:

```
 List (
    List(('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
    List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
    List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
    List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
  )
```

Which is basically the first list combined with the second to create a list of list of tuples?
Was thinking of using a foldLeft with a sliding(2,2) to get my results but cannot just get the right result.

The solution should work with any size and type, like List('a', 'b', 'c') and List("1", "2")

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Trickier than I thought! The first step is to calculate the n-times Cartesian product of l2, which can be done using a combination of `List.fill`, `combinations`, and `permutations` (I have a hard time believing that there is no easier way to do this, but I haven't found any):

```
def prod[T](lst: List[T], n: Int) = List.fill(n)(lst).flatten.combinations(n).flatMap(_.permutations)
```

The value of `n` is determined by the size of list `l1`. In your example `prod(l2, 2)` will give us `List(List(1, 1), List(1, 2), List(2, 1), List(2, 2))`. The rest is just an application of `map` and `zip`. Together, we have

```
prod(l2, l1.size).map(l1.zip(_))
```

Output for `l1 = List('a', 'b', 'c'), l2 = List("1", "2")`:

```
List((a,1), (b,1), (c,1))
List((a,1), (b,1), (c,2))
List((a,1), (b,2), (c,1))
List((a,2), (b,1), (c,1))
List((a,1), (b,2), (c,2))
List((a,2), (b,1), (c,2))
List((a,2), (b,2), (c,1))
List((a,2), (b,2), (c,2))
```

Comment: Waow. Very nice. Quite tricky actually. Thanks for this quick turn around. Learned a lot from your code snippet

Answer (score 8):

The best way is to use a for comprehension. Much cleaner than the accepted solution IMO :)

```
for {
  i1 <- List('a', 'b', 'c')
  i2 <- List(1, 2)
} yield List(i1, i2)
```

Comment: Does not produce the desired result.

Comment: It does not generate the exact output that is asked for by the question, but it answers the question as in the title: it produces all permutations of lists (as `List`). This is what I wanted when Google brought me here.